# JSoup: How to get info which is under some tag?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I have such html page:

```
<a name="robots"></a>
<div class="dnb">
   <div class="info_outer">
      <div class="info">
         <div class="name"><a href="/p/1/">TEXT1</a> <span class="t">TEXT2</span></div>
         <div class="role">SOMEROLE1</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<a name="humans"></a>
<div class="dnb">
   <div class="info_outer">
      <div class="info">
         <div class="name"><a href="/p/1/">TEXT3</a> <span class="t">TEXT4</span></div>
         <div class="role">SOMEROLE2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dnb">
   <div class="info_outer">
      <div class="info">
         <div class="name"><a href="/p/1/">TEXT5</a> <span class="t">TEXT6</span></div>
         <div class="role">SOMEROLE3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dnb">
   <div class="info_outer">
      <div class="info">
         <div class="name"><a href="/p/1/">TEXT7</a> <span class="t">TEXT8</span></div>
         <div class="role">SOMEROLE4</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get info from these divs (names and roles). But only from those, which are under "humans" separator.
Is it possible with JSoup?

Comment: Please close `/a>` tags after `<a href="/p/1/">TEXT`.

Comment: oops, done. Thnks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Learn [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class JSoupSelectors {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File("WeAreTheRobots.xml");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);
        for (Element human : doc.select("a[name=humans]")) {
            Element info = human.nextElementSibling().selectFirst("div.dnb>div.info_outer>div.info");
            String name = info.selectFirst(">div.name>span.t").ownText();
            System.out.println("Name = " + name);
            String role = info.selectFirst(">div.role").ownText();
            System.out.println("Role = " + role);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name = TEXT4
Role = SOMEROLE2
```

Comment: What happens if your link goes dead or changes? This answer will be useless then. You should provide the important parts of the page within your answer itself.

Comment: @notyou OK, I'll try.